# Looking to make an array out of an array variable (2 layer array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

Essentially I am trying to create an array using one of the variables from a previous array (sub-grouping).. The sub array gets created and prints on the page, but the previous array just prints the first 3 letters of the first variable (A, N, D)

```
<script language="javascript">
var name = new Array("Andrew", "Harry", "Jacob");
document.write(name[0] + "<br />");
document.write(name[1] + "<br />");
document.write(name[2] + "<br />");

var andrew = name[0] = new Array("Andrew1", "Andrew2", "Andrew3");
document.write(andrew[0] + "<br />");
document.write(andrew[1] + "<br />");
document.write(andrew[2]);
</script>
```

Comment: generally when you attempt to print the first 3 values of an array an you get 3 letters instead it's because what you think is an array is actually a string and javascript has the same syntax for accessing array by numbered keys as for accessing specific letters of a string.

Comment: ^ That, and your code does not only print the letters A,N,D: http://jsfiddle.net/rCkr6/ . What is actually your problem / question?

Comment: It recognized the Array until I created the new variable form name[0]. Now it only recognizes the andrew Array and prints specific letters of the string of JUST the name array.. Hmm why isn't mine looking like that one?! Mine is giving me A, n, d, Andrew1, Andrew2, Andrew3

Comment: Why are you assigning `var andrew = name[0] = new Array("Andrew1", "Andrew2", "Andrew3");`

Comment: actually, this is a trick question: window.name must be a string, and only a string. if you set it to an array, it will store and reflect the toString() version of the array. make the var name "myName" instead of just "name" and it will be fine. weird, but true.

Comment: Since you already know the cause of this, I encourage you to use a design pattern that encapsulates your variables so that you avoid "collisions" on the global scope. Take a look at the [module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript) for instance.

Comment: That explains why my jsFiddle "worked": The code doesn't run in global scope...

Answer (score 0):

That's a tricky question, nice one!

```
var name = new Array("Andrew", "Harry", "Jacob");
```

is probably rewriting `window.name`: if you add something like

```
document.write(name[0] + "<br />");
```

the output will be `Andrew,Harry,Jacob` as a string.

To avoid this you should use `const` (or `let`) instead of `var` like this:

```
const name = new Array("Andrew", "Harry", "Jacob");
```

or just use a different name.

I suggest you to learn about the difference between `let`, `const`, and `var`

(**TL;DR:** just avoid using `var` for different reasons).